# VS automatically insert reference to project where activity is present

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

there is an issue, when I put a variable to any activity argument, then a reference to project where the activity is present to be added. It causes a problem, because I use only XAMLs in another application and compiler couldn't find assembly of activity project.

For example:

there is empty activity inside a project,

add argument of string,

put Invoke method activity to the activity,

the activity doesn't contain assembly reference to the project

put the argument to Invoke method as Target object,

new reference appears:

```
    <AssemblyReference>ActivityProject</AssemblyReference>
```

How to avoid adding of activity project reference?